# Need some help regarding the Elasticsearch engine and react js

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, elasticsearch, kibana

I hope you are doing well, I need some help regarding the Elasticsearch engine. what I am doing is I am trying to create a search engine I have successfully post my data through kibana to elasticsearch engine. but "**but how can I add the search component of elastyicsearch to my react app**", I have like 4 million records into the kibana index, when I try to search directly from react it take a long time to display records into my frontapp app with nodejs api. below is the code with nodejs but the problem with this code it just gives me 10 records only.

```
router.get('/tweets', (req, res)=>{
let query = {
    index: 'tweets',
    // size: 10000
}
if(req.query.tweets) query.q = `*${req.query.tweets}*`;
client.search(query)
.then(resp => {
    return res.status(200).json({
        tweets: resp.body.hits.hits
    });
})
.catch(err=>{
    console.log(err);
    return res.status(500).json({
        err
    });
});
```

});

Is there any way to impliment elasticsearch component directly to my reactjs app. like with the localhost:9200/index.. directly from the elasticsearch api?

Answer (score -1):

You could use [SearchKit](https://www.npmjs.com/package/searchkit) to directly query elasticsearch from you react app. But be aware that exposing DB services outside of your own infrastructure is bad practice.

You can use the component like this:

```
import {
  SearchkitManager,
  SearchkitProvider,
  SearchkitComponent
} from 'searchkit'

const searchkit = new SearchkitManager(host)

class Render extends SearchkitComponent {

  render(){
    let results = await this.searchkit.reloadSearch()
    return <div>{results}</div>
  }

}

function table(){

  return <SearchkitProvider searchkit={searchkit}>
            <Render />
          </SearchkitProvider>
}
```

Comment: can I call localhost:9200 whici is for elasticsearch engine directly from my react app ?

Answer (score -1):

Your request to Elasticsearch looks a bit strange to me, have you tried to search using a `body` like in the [documentation](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch-js#quick-start)? This line:

```json
if(req.query.tweets) query.q = `*${req.query.tweets}*`;
```

doesn't seem like a correct way to write a query. Which field do you want to search for?

I saw that you tried to use the `size` field, which should be correct. You can also try the following:

```json
client.search({
  index: 'tweets',
  body: {
    size: 1000, // You can put the size here to get more than 10 results
    query: {
      wildcard: { yourfield: `*${req.query.tweets}*` }
    }
  }
}, (err, result) => {
  if (err) console.log(err)
})
```

Comment: and what should be the api to call this from react ?

Comment: Actually, I need create the search engine. I am really new in elasticsearch engine, is it possible that we can add a elasticsearch component into our react App?

Comment: You said that this is your NodeJS application, so it should be your server. Thus, your React application needs to call your endpoint.